# Keyframe spinner not working in firefox & causes fuzzy text

Tags: html, css

I have a keyframe spinner rotating an image on a y axis, plays fine in chrome but no go in firefox. I've tried switching around the html tag to div or span class/id but nothing works. I have other keyframe utilities working fine in firefox just this one doesn't.

Not sure if I should post this as a separate issue but I have a keyframe marquee scrolling text that causes all text in the viewing area to be fuzzy only on firefox but disappears when the marquee is scrolled out of view, if I remove the marquee code, text is fine again. Hoping to get some help on this. The css, html are as follows for the spinner.....thx

```
css
@keyframes spinner {
from {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
to {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
transform: rotateY(360deg); 
} }

.spinner { 
-webkit-animation-name: spinner;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
-webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-ms-animation-name: spinner;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 15;
-ms-animation-duration: .8s;
-ms-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-name: spinner;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-iteration-count: 15;
animation-duration: .8s;
animation-delay: 4s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

html snippet 
<table><tr>
<th>
<span class="spinner"><img src="https://copy.com/8hR4hdxIf2oO0T6x" width="106px" height="210px"></span>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default display type for `<span>` is `display: inline`. Firefox doesn't like that you're trying to 3d transform an inline element. Add `display: block` to your `.spinner`.

Also here's some nicer code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg); 
  }
}

.spinner { 
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner; 
          animation-name: spinner;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
          animation-iteration-count: 15;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
          animation-duration: .8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alejalapeno, that took care of it!